# Interrupts and exceptions dispatching in Linux

Tags: linux, exception, interrupt

By terminology: Assume that interrupts are I/O device character and exceptions can occurs by programmer mistake; for instance: accessing not allocated memory, divide by zero and so on.

Are interrupts and exceptions in Linux dispatched the same way by one routine or only interrupts have one entry point? If so, how are dispatched exceptions?